# High processor utilization when running a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan

I have a stored procedure which was running fine till 12/11 with average execution time under 2 hours. From Tuesday (12/11) onward, the stored procedure is running continuously for more than 3 hours and had to be killed and re-run again manually.

1. On 12/12, we went ahead and scripted out the stored procedure. Dropped the current procedure and recreated it and it worked fine.
2. On 12/13, when the procedure again took a long time to execute, we tried a similar approach of dropping and recreating it, but it didn't work this time. We had to manually run each line of the stored procedure.
3. Today also it is taking a long time to run.

One thing to note is whenever that particular stored procedure is run, the processor utilization shoots up to 95%. We have SQLMonitor tool which depicts the same -

[image]

To eradicate the possibility of parameter sniffing, I cleared out the proc cache using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` and re-ran the procedure at 5:30 AM EST again by dropping and re-creating it. Even after that there is a spike in processor utilization. Below is the current processor utilization after proc cache has been cleared -

[image]

Below is the stored procedure FYI -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Build_Base02_Orders] 

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @Start_Date datetime = getdate();
    declare @Last_Date datetime
    DECLARE @PROMOHIGHDATE INT = (SELECT MAX(FILE_DATE) FROM Stage1_Promotion);

 --Create the Orders from Items

   drop table WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Orders;


With OrdersBase1 as
(
 Select * from WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage3_Orders Orders
 UNION ALL
 Select * from WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage1_Order_Header_HH HH
 WHERE YEAR(ORDDATE) = '2005' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage3_Orders SO WHERE HH.ORDNO = SO.ORDNO)
)

   Select *,

   Row_Number() over (partition by Orders.ORDNO order by Orders.Ordno,Orders.ORDDATE DESC) as lastposition
  into #baseorders
  from OrdersBase1 Orders
    where indid is not null
  and exists
  (select 1 from WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Items items where items.ITMORDNO = orders.ORDNO)


;WITH  Orders AS
  (
   SELECT b.*,OrderLoadDates.File_Date,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HHID ORDER BY HHID,Ordno,Orddate) AS HOSEQNUM,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HHID ORDER BY Orddate DESC) AS HOSEQNUMD,
   P.PROMO_DESC,P.PROMO_QUALIFY_AMT
   FROM #BaseOrders b
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM ufnGetLastOrdHeader(b.ORDNO) a WHERE b.ORDNO=a.ORDER_NUMBER)  OrderLoadDates
   OUTER APPLY ufnGetSTAGE1_Promotion(Offer,@PROMOHIGHDATE) P 


   WHERE b.lastposition = 1
  ),

  ORD_ODATE AS (
  SELECT
  HHID HO_HHID, ORDDATE HO_ODATE
  FROM ORDERS 
  WHERE HOSEQNUM = 1
  ),

  SHPING_CRT_HEADER AS (
  SELECT
  ORDER_NUMBER,  MEDIUM_CODE,  SOURCE_CODE,  CAMPAIGN_CODE,  TERM_CODE,  CONTENT_CODE
  FROM(
  SELECT
  ORDER_NUMBER,
  MEDIUM_CODE,
  SOURCE_CODE,
  CAMPAIGN_CODE,
  TERM_CODE,
  CONTENT_CODE,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CART_ID,ORDER_NUMBER ORDER BY LOAD_DATE DESC) ROW_SELECT
  FROM WinstonBrand.DBO.LTD_Shopping_Cart_Header
  WHERE --MEDIUM_CODE <> ''
  (MEDIUM_CODE <> '' OR SOURCE_CODE <> '' OR CAMPAIGN_CODE <> '' OR TERM_CODE <> '' OR CONTENT_CODE <> '')
  )A
  WHERE ROW_SELECT = 1
  ) 

    SELECT 
    HHID,
    INDID,
    ADDRID,
    COMPID,
    ACCTNO,
    EMAIL_ADD EMAIL,
    Orders.ORDNO,
    CAST(HOSEQNUM AS INT) AS HOSEQNUM,
    CAST(HOSEQNUMD AS INT) AS HOSEQNUMD,
    ORDDATE,
    CAST(ORDTDOL AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDTDOL,
    ORDITEMQTY,
    ORDSHIPQTY,
    CAST(1 AS INT) AS ORDFREQ,
    SOURCE AS ORDSOURCE,
    Ordchanneltype AS ORDCHANNEL,
    CAST(ORDCOGS AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDCOGS,
    CAST(ORDCANCEL AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDCANCEL,
    CAST(ORDRETURN AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDRETURN,
    CAST(ORDSOLDOUT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDSOLDOUT,
    CAST(ORDDISCNT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDDISCNT,
    CAST(ORDERTAX_AMOUNT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS TAXAMT,
    ORDPAYMENT1,
    ORDPAYMENT2,
    ORDCCTYPE,
    OTYPE,
    offer AS ORDOFFER,
    PROMO_DESC,
    PROMO_QUALIFY_AMT,
    keycode AS ORDKEYCODE,
    ORDDER_ENTRY_DATE AS ORDER_ENTRY_DATE,
    CASE WHEN file_date = '20130829' OR file_date > '20130901' THEN TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2),FREIGHT_CHARGES)
    ELSE TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2) ,ORDERFREIGHT_AMOUNT) END
    AS ORDERFREIGHT_AMOUNT,
    CAST(PAYMENT_TYPECODE AS VARCHAR(20))  AS PAYMENT_TYPECODE,
    SERVICE_LEVEL,
    GIFT_FLAG,
    UNDISCOUNTED_FREIGHT AS ORDER_UNDISCOUNTED_FREIGHT_AMOUNT,
    FULLY_SHIPPEDFLAG,
    APPLIED_PROMOCODE,
    PROMO_GIVEN,
    PROMO_DISCOUNT,
    MEMBER_DISCOUNT,
    MEMBER_PROGRAM,
    MEMBER_PROGRAM_SEQ,
    UPSELL_SEQ,
    REPLACE(DETAIL_REFERRING_CAT,',','') DETAIL_REFERRING_CAT,
    REFERRING_DOMAIN,
    REPLACE(REFERRING_WEBSITE,',',' ') REFERRING_WEBSITE,
    REPLACE(SEARCH_PHRASE,',',' ') SEARCH_PHRASE,
    BRAND_CWD_EFFORT,
    BRANDFROM_ORDER,
    CASE WHEN file_date = '20130829' OR file_date > '20130901' THEN
    TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), ADDTL_ORDER_CHARGES) ELSE TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2) ,EST_FREIGHTCOSTS ) END AS PROCESSING_FEE,
    CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDMKTCAT,
    CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDMKTWEB,
    TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2),ACTUAL_FREIGHTCOSTS) AS ORDFREIGHT_EXPENSE,
    CASE
    WHEN CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 AND CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 THEN 'CATALOG & WEB'
    WHEN CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 AND CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) = 0 THEN 'WEB ONLY'
    WHEN CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 AND CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) = 0 THEN 'CATALOG ONLY'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS MRKTCHANNEL,
    HO_ODATE,
    ISNULL(MEDIUM_CODE,'') UTM_MEDIUM_CODE,
    ISNULL(SOURCE_CODE,'') UTM_SOURCE_CODE,
    ISNULL(CAMPAIGN_CODE,'') UTM_CAMPAIGN_CODE,
    ISNULL(TERM_CODE,'') UTM_TERM_CODE,
    ISNULL(CONTENT_CODE,'') UTM_CONTENT_CODE

 INTO WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Orders
    FROM Orders 
    OUTER APPLY ufnGetOrderItemSum(ORDNO ,GIFT) CUSTITEM
    LEFT JOIN ORD_ODATE ON HHID = HO_HHID
    LEFT JOIN SHPING_CRT_HEADER S ON Orders.ORDNO = S.ORDER_NUMBER;


    /****** Object:  Index [NonClusteredIndex-20130929-123603]    Script Date: 9/29/2013 12:37:39 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20130929-123603] ON WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Orders
(
    [HHID] ASC,
    [INDID] ASC,
    [ACCTNO] ASC,
    [ORDNO] ASC,
    --[AOSEQNUM] ASC,
    [HOSEQNUM] ASC,
    [HOSEQNUMD] ASC,
    --[IOSEQNUM] ASC,
    [ORDDATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY];

END
```

Here is the user-defined function `ufnGetLastOrdHeader` used in the stored procedure -

```
USE [WinstonBrand]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ufnGetLastOrdHeader]    Script Date: 12/14/2018 6:50:33 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetLastOrdHeader](@ORDNO varchar(20))
    RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
select ORDER_NUMBER, ORDERFREIGHT_AMOUNT,UNDISCOUNTED_FREIGHT,ACTUAL_FREIGHTCOSTS,EST_FREIGHTCOSTS, ADDTL_ORDER_CHARGES,ADDTL_HANDLING_FEE,FREIGHT_CHARGES, file_date,lastposition from(
   SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, ORDERFREIGHT_AMOUNT,UNDISCOUNTED_FREIGHT,ACTUAL_FREIGHTCOSTS,EST_FREIGHTCOSTS,ADDTL_ORDER_CHARGES,ADDTL_HANDLING_FEE,FREIGHT_CHARGES,file_date
, row_number() over (partition by ORDER_NUMBER order by FILE_DATE DESC) as lastposition
FROM Stage1_Order_Header where ORDER_NUMBER=@ORDNO
) S1_OH where lastposition=1)


GO
```

My question is I am unable to understand why there is a sudden processor utilization when only this procedure is run. Is there anything else other than parameter sniffing which I should look at. The version of SQL Server is 2016-SP1. Let me know if any more details are required.

**EDIT -**

I ran the following 4 commands on my `SSMS` window

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL')
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

After that I started executing my query by making a few changes (since it was being done on a PRODUCTION box). Below is the used query and the execution plan -

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Start_Date datetime = getdate();
declare @Last_Date datetime
DECLARE @PROMOHIGHDATE INT = (SELECT MAX(FILE_DATE) FROM Stage1_Promotion);


With OrdersBase1 as
(
 Select * from WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage3_Orders Orders with (nolock)
 UNION ALL
 Select * from WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage1_Order_Header_HH HH with (nolock)
 WHERE YEAR(ORDDATE) = '2005' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage3_Orders SO with (nolock) WHERE HH.ORDNO = SO.ORDNO)
)

   Select *,

   Row_Number() over (partition by Orders.ORDNO order by Orders.Ordno,Orders.ORDDATE DESC) as lastposition
  into #baseorders
  from OrdersBase1 Orders with (nolock) --WinstonBrand.dbo.stage3_Orders Orders
    where indid is not null
  and exists
  (select 1 from WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Items items with (nolock) where items.ITMORDNO = orders.ORDNO)


;WITH  Orders AS
  (
   SELECT b.*,OrderLoadDates.File_Date,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HHID ORDER BY HHID,Ordno,Orddate) AS HOSEQNUM,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HHID ORDER BY Orddate DESC) AS HOSEQNUMD,
   P.PROMO_DESC,P.PROMO_QUALIFY_AMT
   FROM #BaseOrders b
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM ufnGetLastOrdHeader(b.ORDNO) a WHERE b.ORDNO=a.ORDER_NUMBER)  OrderLoadDates
   OUTER APPLY ufnGetSTAGE1_Promotion(Offer,@PROMOHIGHDATE) P 


   WHERE b.lastposition = 1
  ),

  ORD_ODATE AS (
  SELECT
  HHID HO_HHID, ORDDATE HO_ODATE
  FROM ORDERS 
  WHERE HOSEQNUM = 1
  ),

  SHPING_CRT_HEADER AS (
  SELECT
  ORDER_NUMBER,  MEDIUM_CODE,  SOURCE_CODE,  CAMPAIGN_CODE,  TERM_CODE,  CONTENT_CODE
  FROM(
  SELECT
  ORDER_NUMBER,
  MEDIUM_CODE,
  SOURCE_CODE,
  CAMPAIGN_CODE,
  TERM_CODE,
  CONTENT_CODE,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CART_ID,ORDER_NUMBER ORDER BY LOAD_DATE DESC) ROW_SELECT
  FROM WinstonBrand.DBO.LTD_Shopping_Cart_Header with (nolock)
  WHERE --MEDIUM_CODE <> ''
  (MEDIUM_CODE <> '' OR SOURCE_CODE <> '' OR CAMPAIGN_CODE <> '' OR TERM_CODE <> '' OR CONTENT_CODE <> '')
  )A
  WHERE ROW_SELECT = 1
  ) 

    SELECT 
    HHID,
    INDID,
    ADDRID,
    COMPID,
    ACCTNO,
    EMAIL_ADD EMAIL,
    Orders.ORDNO,
    CAST(HOSEQNUM AS INT) AS HOSEQNUM,
    CAST(HOSEQNUMD AS INT) AS HOSEQNUMD,
    ORDDATE,
    CAST(ORDTDOL AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDTDOL,
    ORDITEMQTY,
    ORDSHIPQTY,
    CAST(1 AS INT) AS ORDFREQ,
    SOURCE AS ORDSOURCE,
    Ordchanneltype AS ORDCHANNEL,
    CAST(ORDCOGS AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDCOGS,
    CAST(ORDCANCEL AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDCANCEL,
    CAST(ORDRETURN AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDRETURN,
    CAST(ORDSOLDOUT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDSOLDOUT,
    CAST(ORDDISCNT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDDISCNT,
    CAST(ORDERTAX_AMOUNT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS TAXAMT,
    ORDPAYMENT1,
    ORDPAYMENT2,
    ORDCCTYPE,
    OTYPE,
    offer AS ORDOFFER,
    PROMO_DESC,
    PROMO_QUALIFY_AMT,
    keycode AS ORDKEYCODE,
    ORDDER_ENTRY_DATE AS ORDER_ENTRY_DATE,
    --Freight_Charges,
    CASE WHEN file_date = '20130829' OR file_date > '20130901' THEN TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2),FREIGHT_CHARGES)
    ELSE TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2) ,ORDERFREIGHT_AMOUNT) END
    AS ORDERFREIGHT_AMOUNT,
    CAST(PAYMENT_TYPECODE AS VARCHAR(20))  AS PAYMENT_TYPECODE,
    SERVICE_LEVEL,
    GIFT_FLAG,
    UNDISCOUNTED_FREIGHT AS ORDER_UNDISCOUNTED_FREIGHT_AMOUNT,
    --ACTUAL_FREIGHTCOSTS as FREIGHT_EXPENSE,
    FULLY_SHIPPEDFLAG,
    APPLIED_PROMOCODE,
    PROMO_GIVEN,
    PROMO_DISCOUNT,
    MEMBER_DISCOUNT,
    MEMBER_PROGRAM,
    MEMBER_PROGRAM_SEQ,
    UPSELL_SEQ,
    REPLACE(DETAIL_REFERRING_CAT,',','') DETAIL_REFERRING_CAT,
    REFERRING_DOMAIN,
    REPLACE(REFERRING_WEBSITE,',',' ') REFERRING_WEBSITE,
    REPLACE(SEARCH_PHRASE,',',' ') SEARCH_PHRASE,
    BRAND_CWD_EFFORT,
    BRANDFROM_ORDER,
    CASE WHEN file_date = '20130829' OR file_date > '20130901' THEN
    TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), ADDTL_ORDER_CHARGES) ELSE TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2) ,EST_FREIGHTCOSTS ) END AS PROCESSING_FEE,
    CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDMKTCAT,
    CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) AS ORDMKTWEB,
    TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2),ACTUAL_FREIGHTCOSTS) AS ORDFREIGHT_EXPENSE,
    CASE
    WHEN CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 AND CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 THEN 'CATALOG & WEB'
    WHEN CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 AND CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) = 0 THEN 'WEB ONLY'
    WHEN CAST(ORDMKTCAT AS NUMERIC(9,2)) > 0 AND CAST (ORDMKTWEB AS NUMERIC(9,2)) = 0 THEN 'CATALOG ONLY'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS MRKTCHANNEL,
    HO_ODATE,
    ISNULL(MEDIUM_CODE,'') UTM_MEDIUM_CODE,
    ISNULL(SOURCE_CODE,'') UTM_SOURCE_CODE,
    ISNULL(CAMPAIGN_CODE,'') UTM_CAMPAIGN_CODE,
    ISNULL(TERM_CODE,'') UTM_TERM_CODE,
    ISNULL(CONTENT_CODE,'') UTM_CONTENT_CODE

 INTO WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Orders_DBA
    FROM Orders with (nolock)
    OUTER APPLY ufnGetOrderItemSum(ORDNO ,GIFT) CUSTITEM
    LEFT JOIN ORD_ODATE ON HHID = HO_HHID
    LEFT JOIN SHPING_CRT_HEADER S ON Orders.ORDNO = S.ORDER_NUMBER;


    /****** Object:  Index [NonClusteredIndex-20130929-123603]    Script Date: 9/29/2013 12:37:39 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20130929-123603_DBA] ON WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Orders_DBA
(
    [HHID] ASC,
    [INDID] ASC,
    [ACCTNO] ASC,
    [ORDNO] ASC,
    [HOSEQNUM] ASC,
    [HOSEQNUMD] ASC,
    [ORDDATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY];

SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

Below are the messages printed on SSMS Result window -

> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>   Table 'Stage1_Promotion'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2248, physical
>   reads 4, read-ahead reads 2198, lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 68 ms.
>   Table 'Items'. Scan count 6, logical reads 11895581, physical reads
>   8481, read-ahead reads 11793819, lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Stage3_Orders'. Scan count 12,
>   logical reads 2258024, physical reads 41, read-ahead reads 2257333,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Stage1_Order_Header_HH'. Scan count 6, logical reads 435021,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 435021, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Worktable'. Scan
>   count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
>   logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   'Workfile'. Scan count 50, logical reads 83864, physical reads 7283,
>   read-ahead reads 76581, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 1370469 ms,  elapsed time =
>   836897 ms.
>
> SQL Server parse and compile time:  CPU time = 5734 ms, elapsed time =
>   5827 ms. Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 203343290, logical reads
>   1778461093, physical reads 470694, read-ahead reads 2151647, lob
>   logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   'LTD_Shopping_Cart_Header'. Scan count 1, logical reads 404060,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 404060, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Workfile'. Scan count
>   3752, logical reads 9917704, physical reads 1903935, read-ahead reads
>   13387577, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead
>   reads 0. Table 'Items'. Scan count 1, logical reads 11895581, physical
>   reads 6902, read-ahead reads 11292947, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Stage1_Order_Header'.
>   Scan count 2, logical reads 2068767, physical reads 4, read-ahead
>   reads 1034391, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   '#baseorders_________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000001C31'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4239764, physical reads 140, read-ahead
>   reads 1994015, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Stage1_Promotion'. Scan count 2, logical
>   reads 4496, physical reads 4, read-ahead reads 2198, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Warning: Null value
>   is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 7282594 ms,  elapsed time =
>   8292072 ms. Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical
>   reads 0, read-ahead reads 521245, lob logical reads 0, lob physical
>   reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Orders_DBA'. Scan count 1,
>   logical reads 2343169, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 31057, lob
>   logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 298765 ms,  elapsed time =
>   312090 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Below is the Resource Utilization graph for the time period the query ran. The query started to run at `15:43 EST` and took `2:37:27` hours to complete.

[image]

Here is the [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1GD0xflE) to the query plan.

Comment: Re-creating the procedure doesn't "eradicate the possibility of parameter sniffing". If you have query stored turned on then compare the plans that it logged. I not, then you need to get to the plans from both a good and a bad execution and take it from there. Looking back at the proc, I now see that you don't even have any parameters to the proc, so there's nothing to sniff. Definitely means you want to compare the plans...

Comment: You should also update the statistics just in case, as @jadarnel said, the execution plan is important to know where the most of the work is being done.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - I posted the query plan at the asked URL for the **EDIT** mentioned in my question.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh after you post the plan to pastetheplan.com, you need to edit your post with the URL for it.

Comment: @alroc - Grr. My bad. Done!

Comment: Have you turned on the Query Store?  It was built to help situations like you describe. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing more about the table structure, and having no test data these are the things you could try.

**Part 1: insert into #baseorders ('less' important in comparison)**

In this part, some changes can be made on the where clause, so a function is not applied to ORDDATE. This part takes 22Min of CPU time according to the stats.

```
With OrdersBase1 as
(
 Select * from WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage3_Orders Orders with (nolock)
 UNION ALL
 Select * from WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage1_Order_Header_HH HH with (nolock)
 WHERE ORDDATE > '2004-12-31 23:59:59.999' AND ORDDATE <  '2006-01-01 00:00:00.000' -- Functions on Columns are bad for indexing.
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WinstonBrand.dbo.Stage3_Orders SO with (nolock) WHERE HH.ORDNO = SO.ORDNO)
)

   Select *,

   Row_Number() over (partition by Orders.ORDNO order by Orders.Ordno,Orders.ORDDATE DESC) as lastposition
  into #baseorders
  from OrdersBase1 Orders with (nolock) --WinstonBrand.dbo.stage3_Orders Orders
    where indid is not null
  and exists
  (select 1 from WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Items items with (nolock) where items.ITMORDNO = orders.ORDNO)
```

However, the changes will not do a lot unless we have an index on Stage1_Order_Header_H (ORDNO,ORDDATE)

[image]

Ofcourse, since we are doing a select *, The index will need to cover the entire table.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Stage1_Order_Header_H
ON dbo.Stage1_Order_Header_H(ORDNO,ORDDATE)
INCLUDE(everything)
```

This is not ideal. 
As a side note, here is a group by [session](http://groupby.libsyn.com/improving-select-query-performance-by-erik-darling) on improving select *

What you could try, is creating clustered or nonclustered columnstore indexes on the tables involved if you are just using it for processing, and not doing a lot of key lookups on it. Columnstore makes batch processing much faster.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCX_Stage1_Order_Header_H
 ON dbo.Stage1_Order_Header_H
```

**Part 2: Insert INTO WinstonBrand_Base.dbo.Orders_DBA**

Or as i would like to call it, sortfest.
This is the most important part, with 2:01:22.594 CPU Time.

*Exhibit A:*

[image]

*Digging deeper into the evidence*

On the index spool, we have an CONVERT IMPLICIT, we will need to remove that.
[image]

Could it be that ORDER_NUMBER is nvarchar,
and that this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetLastOrdHeader](@ORDNO varchar(20))
```

should be changed to this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetLastOrdHeader](@ORDNO nvarchar(20))
```

However, it is converting on the parameter, not on the column, so performance based it is not the worst that this is happening. If it is fixable, it should be fixed.

After that, i would try adding this index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Stage1_Order_Header
on dbo.Stage1_Order_Header(ORDER_NUMBER,FILE_DATE)
INCLUDE( ORDERFREIGHT_AMOUNT,UNDISCOUNTED_FREIGHT,ACTUAL_FREIGHTCOSTS,EST_FREIGHTCOSTS,ADDTL_ORDER_CHARGES,ADDTL_HANDLING_FEE,FREIGHT_CHARGES)
```

**To try and remove 2 of the sorts. Sorting is very expensive.**

*Just to be clear, looking into removing the function itself or rewriting is it also a thing to look into, but without table definitions and a data set, it would be hard to test.*

*Exhibit B:*

[image]

```
  CREATE INDEX IX_LTD_Shopping_Cart_Header_ORDER_NUMBER_CART_ID_LOAD_DATE
  on DBO.LTD_Shopping_Cart_Header(ORDER_NUMBER,CART_ID,LOAD_DATE)
  INCLUDE(

  MEDIUM_CODE,
  SOURCE_CODE,
  CAMPAIGN_CODE,
  TERM_CODE,
  CONTENT_CODE,
  )
```

*Exhibit C.1 :*

[image]
This one is a bit trickier, some selects are selecting everything in the temp table, but you might see results by adding the following index in the procedure.

```
   CREATE INDEX IX_BaseOrders
ON #BaseOrders(HHID,Ordno,Orddate)
include(everything)
```

*Exhibit C.2*

[image]

**In short**

In short, the sorts are the first thing I would try to improve, since these will take a lot of CPU time. Rewriting the query, the functions, omitting unneeded data, ... would be my first approach, but indexing to remove these sorts should help nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you @Randi for the detailed solution. I will definitely try this out and let you know.

Comment: For the time being the DEV team has implemented the use of local temp tables rather than CTEs and strangely enough it has done the trick. From my understanding, using temp tables will increase I/O on the server. But there is no spike in processor utilization. I think team will stick to the current solution, but your inputs are highly appreciated @Randi.